# Max function on Hive Bucket

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table structure in HIVE as below -

```
create table if not exists cdp_compl_status
(
EmpNo INT,
RoleCapability STRING,
EmpPUCode STRING,
SBUCode STRING,
CertificationCode STRING,
CertificationTitle STRING,
Competency STRING,
Certification_Type STRING,
Certification_Group STRING,
Contact_Based_Program_Y_N STRING,
ExamDate DATE,
Onsite_Offshore STRING,
AttendedStatus STRING,
Marks INT,
Result STRING,
Status STRING,
txtPlanCategory STRING,
SkillID1 INT,
Complexity STRING
)
CLUSTERED BY (Marks) INTO 5 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
TBLPROPERTIES('created on' = '12 Aug');
```

Now, I want to query MAX(MARKS) from every bucket in the table. If I do -

```
SELECT MAX(MARKS) from cdp_compl_status;
```

It shows Maximum Marks from the whole table. Is there any way, I can find out `MAX(MARKS)` from every bucket?

Comment: i don't think you can get `max` by bucket.

Comment: Finding out the max per bucket would have no meaning.  You don't know what `marks` are in a bucket.

Answer (score 2):

As you have divided Table into 5 Buckets...
Data split into buckets on basis of % function i.e. eg:
`marks%5==0` into 1st bucket
`marks%5==1` into 2nd bucket
`marks%5==2` into 3rd bucket
`marks%5==3` into 4th bucket
`marks%5==4` into 5th bucket

So you need to write 5 queries like this one:
`Select max(marks) from cdp_compl_status where marks%5=0;` -- for max in first bucket

I guess this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use tablesample:

```
select max(marks),min(marks),avg(marks) from cert_comp_status_buck
tablesample(bucket 1 out of 5 on marks);

select max(marks),min(marks),avg(marks) from cert_comp_status_buck
tablesample(bucket 2 out of 5 on marks);

select max(marks),min(marks),avg(marks) from cert_comp_status_buck
tablesample(bucket 3 out of 5 on marks);

select max(marks),min(marks),avg(marks) from cert_comp_status_buck
tablesample(bucket 4 out of 5 on marks);

select max(marks),min(marks),avg(marks) from cert_comp_status_buck
tablesample(bucket 5 out of 5 on marks);
```